# How to remove ticks from the top and right axes of a plot generated with PGFPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to remove ticks from the top and right axes of the bounding box of a plot generated with pgfplots. Any help appreciated.

Here is sample code which generates unwanted ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
celc fahr
0  32
20 68
40 104
60 140
80 176
100 212
}\mytable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={\si{\degreeCelsius}},
                 ylabel={\si{\degree F}}]
    \addplot table \mytable;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result, with unwanted ticks in top and right:

[image: example]

I realize this sounds very basic but a search for examples to guide me has not panned out.

Comment: Search also the manual with `axis lines`.

Comment: @Jake I do mean remove from top and right. I tried `tick pos=right` but this turns off ticks on the left y line AND the bottom line and sets the tick label on the top x axis.

Comment: @Jake: to clarify, the plot shown above places the y label and y tick labels on the left side which is also not what I want but was readily fixed with `y dir = reverse`.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for your help, I made the edits you recommended. Sorry also about the confusion, the example shown is a watered down version of what I want to do. And no, I did not use `y dir = reverse`, instead I used `yticklabel pos=right`, I mixed those up in my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `xtick pos`, `ytick pos` keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotstableread{
celc fahr
0  32
20 68
40 104
60 140
80 176
100 212
}\mytable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={\si{\degreeCelsius}},
                 ylabel={\si{\degree F}},
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left]
    \addplot table \mytable;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ... or `tick pos=left`, which sets `xtick pos=left` and `ytick pos=left` simultaneously.

Comment: @Jake yes; however, I wan't sure from the original description if Try Hard wanted left also for the y-axis (the question mentions "right"), so I decided to present both keys for individual control.

Comment: Very intuitive that the bottom of x is on the left... Is there some logical reason behind this or did they just not want to handle x and y differently?

Comment: @luator Probably by coincidence, from pgfplots manual "Note that the keys left and bottom are aliases for `lower`." (i.e. they both correspond to smaller value of the coordinate)