# pgfplots - Remove tickmarks on right and top of plot

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

Hello TEX/PGF/Tikz community,

I have trouble with tikz as I would like to remove the tick marks on the right and on the top of this plot

[image]

see the ugly red 'circle' markings in the picture :). I know one can remove the tick marks on both sides but I only want to remove the tick marks on one side. Is there anyone who knows how I can solve this problem. And I would also like to know how I can make the other tick marks smaller.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \newlength{\widthLarger}
    \setlength{\widthLarger}{10cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    height=8cm,
    width=8cm}% most (standard) used width

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        % Dimensions of plot
        % used default size determined in \pgfplotsset
        % Domain for values
        xmin = 1,
        xmax = 20,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 250,
        % Axis labeling
        xlabel = {Frequency [Hz]},
        ylabel = {Amplitude},
        title = {Test plot},
        %legend style = {at={(1.05,0.95)}, anchor = north east, cells = {anchor = west}}
        ]
        \addplot [red, mark = none, thick, smooth] coordinates{(1,20)(5,60)(7,90)(17,150)};
        \legend{Graph1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First half is already covered in [tikz pgf - How to remove ticks from the top and right axes of a plot generated with PGFPlots? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125299/how-to-remove-ticks-from-the-top-and-right-axes-of-a-plot-generated-with-pgfplot)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left`, or alternatively `tick pos=left` which does the same thing. The length of the ticks is defined by the `tickwidth` parameter.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \newlength{\widthLarger}
    \setlength{\widthLarger}{10cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    height=8cm,
    width=8cm}% most (standard) used width

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        % Dimensions of plot
        % used default size determined in \pgfplotsset
        % Domain for values
        xmin = 1,
        xmax = 20,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 250,
        % Axis labeling
        xlabel = {Frequency [Hz]},
        ylabel = {Amplitude},
        title = {Test plot},
        %legend style = {at={(1.05,0.95)}, anchor = north east, cells = {anchor = west}},
        % position of ticks
        xtick pos=bottom,
        ytick pos=left,
        % or alternatively
        %tick pos=left,
        % length of ticks
        tickwidth=1mm
        ]
        \addplot [red, mark = none, thick, smooth] coordinates{(1,20)(5,60)(7,90)(17,150)};
        \legend{Graph1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MrYouMath What do you mean? `tick pos=left` sets both `xtick pos=left` and `ytick pos=left`, and `left` is the same as `bottom`, so the two are equivalent.

Comment: @MrYouMath Read the description of those keys in the manual. In the manual for `pgfplots` 1.14 it is in section 4.15.2 *Tick Alignment: Position and Shifts*.

Comment: I mean that trying "ytick pos = left," or "xtick pos = bottom," did result in an error. Removing both and replacing them with "tick pos = left" worked. But nevermind, I will come back to TeXSE if I need this in a plot :).

Comment: @MrYouMath Ok, but what you actually said was that both worked. Which error did you get?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing comment:). Here is the error message: ! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'left' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/xtick pos'. I am going to ignore this key.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{axis}

Comment: @MrYouMath I would guess you have an older version of `pgfplots`, where `left` wasn't implemented yet. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsversion
\end{document}` will tell you which version you have. (I have 1.15, not 1.14 as I said above.)

Comment: How can I update pgfplots?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64233/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-mryoumath).