# pgfplots, x- and y-axis tick lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am new to latex and this is my first post, so I am doing my best.
I am plotting data (csv file) with pgfplots and so far it is working. But there some things I want to change and can not find the solution elsewhere.

**Problems (Picture is down below)**

1. Since my data is going into the billions a "10^8" is being displayed to adjust the y-axis which is in single digits. Since I already have the y-axis labeled as "... in $ Billions" I do not want that adjustment. Is there maybe a simple command or do I have to adjust my data?
2. The top x-axis as well as the left y-axis have "tick lines". Which command do I have to use to elimate those?

Thank you very much :)

**This is my code so far:**

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[height=9cm, width=\textwidth,
    legend pos=north west,
    xmin=1995,
    xmax=2018,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
    ymin=0,
    ymajorgrids,
    xlabel=Year,
    ylabel=Trade in \$ Billions],
\addplot table [ x=Year, y=Export, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
\addlegendentry{$Exports$}
\addplot table [ x=Year, y=Import, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
\addlegendentry{$Imports$}
\addplot table [ x=Year, y=Total Trade, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
\addlegendentry{$Total Trade$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: In the top left corner]

Answer (score 4):

- To hide the exponent "10^8" of y-axis, use `ytick scale label code/.code={}`
- To remove the ticks on top and right axes, use `xtick pos=lower, ytick pos=left`, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125304). These two options are both initialized to `both`.

To learn more, you can search for the mentioned option names in the manual of package `pgfplots`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids,
    title={Before}
  ]
    \addplot coordinates {
      (20,0.0005)
      (40,0.0010)
      (60,0.0020)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids,
    title={After},
    ytick scale label code/.code={},
    xtick pos=lower,
    ytick pos=left
  ]
    \addplot coordinates {
      (20,0.0005)
      (40,0.0010)
      (60,0.0020)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Always impressed by the speed and kindness of this community :D